# Propose correct design for method with just different return types

Tags: c#, .net

In some cases I want my method to return `XDocument` object and in other cases `XmlDocument`.

Solutions I see:

1. Use return type `object`
2. Create two different methods (of diff names); one returning `XDocument` and other returning `XmlDocument`.
3. Create method overloads with different `out` parameter types.

Can you propose good design?

Comment: The second solution is much better than the others (the first especially is an unbelievably bad idea). But the best advice that I can suggest is a) tell us *what you want to achieve*, not how you think it should be achieved and b) familiarize yourself better with the concept of *abstraction*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generic method:

```
public T GetDocument<T>();
```

which returns an `XDocument` when called as `GetDocument<XDocument>` and an `XmlDocument` when called as `GetDocument<XmlDocument>`.

Within the method you could do

```
if (T is XmlDocument) ...
else if (T is XDocument) ...
else throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type for T");
```

Answer (score 0):

what language are you using? vb.net?

```
if <condition 1> then
 Return XDocument
else if <condition 2> then
 Return XmlDocument
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say create a method that shares as much code as possible as private/protected. Then, when you have to specialize what is returned to a caller, create two public methods that are strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can have overload return types in following way too....

```
                public interface IXDocument
                {
                    XDocument GetDocument(string str);
                }
                public interface IXMLDocument
                {
                    XMLDocument GetDocument(string str);
                }



            public class Document : IXDocument, IXMLDocument
            {
                public XDocument IXDocument.GetDocument(string str)
                {
                    // return XDocument
                }
                public XMLDocument IXMLDocument.GetDocument(string str)
                {
                    // return XMLDocument
                }

            }


            XDocument returnedXDocument = ((IXDocument)Instance of Docuement).GetDocument("value");
            // - and/or
            XMLDocument returnedXMLDocument = ((IXMLDocument)Instance of Docuement).GetDocument("value");
```